# Can't make the computer with ubuntu installed act as a server in a simple fie sharing program

Tags: python, linux, sockets, ubuntu

Code for server:

```
import socket
import os.path
host=''
port=9988
sock=socket.socket()
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((host,port))
sock.listen(5)
while True:
    new_socket,(h,p)=sock.accept()
    print "Client connected with ip address : "+h
    f=new_socket.recv(1024)
    print h+" asking for "+f
    if os.path.isfile(f) and os.access(f, os.R_OK):
            temp = open(f,'rb')
            size=os.path.getsize(f)
            var='y '+str(size)
            new_socket.send(var)
            ch=new_socket.recv(1024)
            if ch=='y':
                new_socket.send(temp.read())
            print f+" sent successfully to "+h
            temp.close()
            new_socket.close()
    else:
            new_socket.send("n")
            new_socket.close()
sock.close()
```

Code for client:

```
import socket
host="ip address of computer as server"
port=9988
while True:
    soc=socket.socket()
    soc.connect((host,port))
    f=raw_input("Enter the name of the file you wish to download : ")
    soc.send(f)
    msg=soc.recv(1024)
    if msg[0]=='y':
        print "The file exists, total size : "+msg[2:]
        ch=raw_input("Download ? (y/n) : ")
        if ch=='y'or ch=='Y':
            fo=open("new_"+f,'wb')
            soc.send('y')
            rcv=soc.recv(1024)
            fo.write(rcv)
            rcv=soc.recv(1024)
            while rcv:
                fo.write(rcv)
                rcv=soc.recv(1024)
            print "File download complete. "
            fo.close()
    else:
        print "No file with this name found on the server. "
    ch=raw_input("Want to continue? (y/n) : ")
    if ch=='n'or ch=='N':
        break
    soc.close()
```

I get the error message as ***error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*** when I run the server code on my ubuntu laptop and the client code on a windows laptop.

The file sharing works just fine if I run server on windows and client on ubuntu. How do I make computer with ubuntu act as server?

It works on localhost.

Comment: Sounds like you have firewall problems, not problems with your code.

Comment: Like @tripleee said. See if using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` works. I answered your question with a working example based on your code.

Comment: @Harvey Localhost and 127.0.0.1 work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to disable ufw and selinux, and try again. Use `netstat` command, to see what ports are opened and in "listening" state on you server, also, you can use `tcpdump` to see what's happening over your network.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, using Python 2.7.9, this code based on yours works:

server.py

```
import socket
import os.path
host=''
port=9988
sock=socket.socket()
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((host,port))
sock.listen(5)
while True:
    new_socket,(h,p)=sock.accept()
    print "Client connected with ip address :", (h,p)
    new_socket.send("hello " + str((h,p)))
    new_socket.close()
sock.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import time
host="127.0.0.1"
port=9988
while True:
    soc=socket.socket()
    soc.connect((host,port))
    while True:
        msg=soc.recv(1024)
        if not msg:
            break
        print 'received: ' + msg
    soc.close()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
$ python server.py
Client connected with ip address : ('127.0.0.1', 52915)
Client connected with ip address : ('127.0.0.1', 52918)

$ python client.py
received: hello ('127.0.0.1', 52915)
received: hello ('127.0.0.1', 52918)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that I wrote for server client FTP on ubuntu

Client

```
import socket
import sys
import os
import time
def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000
    start=0
    end=0
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    filename = input("Enter Filename -> ")
    if filename != 'q':
        s.send(filename.encode())
        data = s.recv(1024)
        data=data.decode()
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filesize = int(data[6:])
            message = input("File exists, " + str(filesize) +" Bytes, download? (Y/N)? -> ")
            if message == 'Y':
                s.send("OK".encode())
                start=time.clock()
                f = open(filename, 'wb')
                data = s.recv(1024)
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while totalRecv < filesize:
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    if sys.platform=='linux' or sys.platform=='linux2':
                        os.system('clear')
                    else:
                        os.system('cls')
                    print ("{0:.2f}".format((totalRecv/float(filesize))*100)+ "% Downloading Done")
                end=time.clock()
                end=(end-start)/60
                print ("Download Completed! Downloading took %.4f minutes"%end)
                end=end*60
                speed=(filesize/1024)/end
                print("Average Download Speed:%.2f Kbps"%speed)
                time.sleep(6)
                f.close()
            else:
                print("Program Terminated")
                time.sleep(2)

        else:
            print ("File Does Not Exist!")
            time.sleep(2)

    s.close()

Main()
```

Server

```
import socket
import threading
import os

def RetrFile(name, sock):
    filename = sock.recv(1024)
    filename=filename.decode()
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        data="EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))
        try:
            sock.send(data.encode())
            userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
            userResponse=userResponse.decode()
            if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
                    while bytesToSend != "":
                        bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                        sock.send(bytesToSend)
        except:
            print("Connection Error")
    else:
        sock.send("ERR ".encode())

    sock.close()
    print("Connection Closed")

def Main():
    host = ''
    port = 5000


    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(5)

    print ("Server Started.")
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print ("client connedted ip:<" + str(addr) + ">")
        t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("RetrThread", c))
        t.start()

    s.close()

Main()
```